# android ndk open gl es 2 setup without java

Tags: android, c++, opengl-es, android-ndk

I want to make a android application which draws open `gl` graphics completely from native code, in other words I'm using `native_app_glue` in my c/c++ code.

However I cant find a single resource on the internet that points to using open gl completely from native code ! 
All the links I found show how can I use the `GLSurfaceView` in java and then make a `JNI` call to C/C++ for each `onDraw()` call. THIS IS EXACTLY WHAT I DON'T WANT TO DO!!

Even the `hello-gl2` sample in the `ndk` uses the same approach!

I do understand that the native app glue does includes some java code behind the scenes to start up the activity, but I dont want any more frequent JNI calls after that.

Instead I want to setup initialisation and call backs for the screen in native code, by that I want to setup the display surface and its corresponding call backs in my native code and not through java.

1.what are the data structures representing a surface (or window display) in `NDK`?

2.How do I get access to them and get attributes like width and height of the display (in native code)?

3.How do I draw onto that display (since there is no on draw callback I assume I need to make a loop to draw call manually but in that case how do I know that last frame has finished rendering?)

Comment: You can always compile standalone executable and push it thru adb and run it from adb shell (NOTE I'm not saying this is the BEST KNOWN METHOD for native dev on android, but its a possibility)

Comment: No that's not what I'm looking for! I edited the title to be more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the NDK Samples.  There is one here:
\android-ndk\samples\native-activity

On-line link:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NativeActivity.html

Comment: Is that the only efficient way? I mean those calls are open gl specific so would they interfere with other widgets like the menu?

Comment: Seriously this info must be dug out and should be documented in a better way than just a example snippet in the references!

Comment: What egl version android uses (with gles2.0)?

Comment: IIRC, Android provided support for EGL 1.0 until 4.2 (API 17), when it added support for EGL 1.4.  The EGL context and surface is set per-thread with `eglMakeCurrent()`, and it doesn't matter whether you configure it from Java or native code.  Once it's set up, you just draw whatever you want with GLES, then call `eglSwapBuffers()` to submit the new buffer -- from Java code, native code, or a mix of the two.  The NativeActivity class is just for people who don't want any Java code.

Comment: some good info there! but how do I know that its time to swap buffers and draw the next frame (there is no onDrawFrame in native code , or is there?)

Answer (score 4):

Below is a simple C program (without Manifest/Java etc...) that spins a triangle for 20 seconds. This is just for information purpose (not the recommended way for creating an Android app). It requires access rights to the 'graphics' group (which is the case if you run it through ADB).

How to compile it:

1) get android NDK from http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html

2) install toolchain:

```
  ./android-ndk-r9b/build/tools/make-standalone-toolchain.sh        \
      --platform=android-17 --toolchain=arm-linux-androideabi-4.7   \
      --system=linux-x86_64 --install-dir=where_you_want_to_install
```

3) get libui.so from device:

```
  adb pull /system/lib/libui.so
```

4) compilation:

```
 arm-linux-androideabi-gcc main.c -lGLESv1_CM -lEGL -landroid -L. -lui -o gles_test
```

To run the program, you will need access to the 'graphics' group, which is the case if you run it through ADB (but not if you run it from a terminal, e.g., TerminalIDE)

```
/* Program largely inspired from:                                                            */
/* http://jiggawatt.org/badc0de/android/index.html                                           */
/* http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/setting-up-native-opengl-es-on-android-platforms */
/* http://www.brucesutherland.co.uk/android-ndk/opengl-es-2-0-android-ndk-game-programming/  */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <EGL/egl.h>
#include <GLES/gl.h>
#include <android/native_window.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/times.h> 


/* returns current time in seconds */
double now() {
    struct tms now_tms ;
    return (double)(times(&now_tms)) / 100.0 ;
}

/* from libui.so (get it from the device using adb pull /system/lib/libui.so) */
extern NativeWindowType android_createDisplaySurface();

NativeWindowType displayWindow;

const EGLint config16bpp[] = {
    EGL_RENDERABLE_TYPE, EGL_OPENGL_ES_BIT,
    EGL_SURFACE_TYPE,    EGL_WINDOW_BIT, 
    EGL_RED_SIZE,   5,
    EGL_GREEN_SIZE, 6,
    EGL_BLUE_SIZE,  5,
    EGL_NONE
};


const EGLint config24bpp[] = {
    EGL_RENDERABLE_TYPE, EGL_OPENGL_ES_BIT,
    EGL_SURFACE_TYPE,    EGL_WINDOW_BIT, 
    EGL_RED_SIZE,   8,
    EGL_GREEN_SIZE, 8,
    EGL_BLUE_SIZE,  8,
    EGL_NONE
};

const EGLint config32bpp[] = {
    EGL_RENDERABLE_TYPE, EGL_OPENGL_ES_BIT,
    EGL_SURFACE_TYPE,    EGL_WINDOW_BIT, 
    EGL_RED_SIZE,   8,
    EGL_GREEN_SIZE, 8,
    EGL_BLUE_SIZE,  8,
    EGL_ALPHA_SIZE, 8,
    EGL_NONE
};


GLfloat colors[3][4] = {
    {1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f},
    {0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f},
    {0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f}
};

GLfloat vertices[3][3] = {
    {0.0f, 0.7f, 0.0f},
    {-0.7f, -0.7f, 0.0f},
    {0.7f, -0.7f, 0.0f}
};


void draw_tri() {
    glViewport(
        0,
        0,
        ANativeWindow_getWidth(displayWindow),
        ANativeWindow_getHeight(displayWindow)
    );
    glRotatef(0.5, 0, 0, 1) ;

    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

    glColorPointer(4, GL_FLOAT, 0, colors);
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices);

    /* Draw the triangle (3 vertices) */
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
}


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    EGLint majorVersion, minorVersion;
    EGLContext eglContext;
    EGLSurface eglSurface;
    EGLConfig eglConfig;
    EGLDisplay eglDisplay = eglGetDisplay(EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY);
    EGLint format;
    const EGLint* config = NULL ;
    int numConfigs;
    int windowFormat;
    double start_time  = now() ;


    /* 
     * create a window surface that covers the entire screen.
     * This function is from libui. 
     */
    displayWindow = android_createDisplaySurface();

    eglInitialize(eglDisplay, &majorVersion, &minorVersion);
    printf("GL version: %d.%d\n",majorVersion,minorVersion);

    if(displayWindow == 0) {
       printf("Could not create window\n") ;
       printf("Started from an on-device shell ?\n") ;
       printf("use: adb shell <path_to_exe>/%s\n",argv[0]) ;
       exit(-1) ;
    }

    /* get the format of the window. */
    windowFormat = ANativeWindow_getFormat(displayWindow) ;

    printf("Window specs: %d*%d format=%d\n",
           ANativeWindow_getWidth(displayWindow),
           ANativeWindow_getHeight(displayWindow),
           windowFormat
    ) ;

    /* choose the config according to the format of the window. */
    switch(windowFormat) {
     case WINDOW_FORMAT_RGBA_8888:
       config = config32bpp ;
       break ;
     case WINDOW_FORMAT_RGBX_8888:
       config = config24bpp ;       
       break ;
     case WINDOW_FORMAT_RGB_565:
       config = config16bpp ;       
       break ;
     default:
       printf("Unknown window format\n") ;
       exit(-1) ;
    }

    if (!eglChooseConfig(eglDisplay, config32bpp, &eglConfig, 1, &numConfigs)) {
        printf("eglChooseConfig failed\n");
        if (eglContext==0) printf("Error code: %x\n", eglGetError());
        exit(-1) ;
    }

    eglContext = eglCreateContext(eglDisplay, eglConfig,  EGL_NO_CONTEXT, NULL);
    printf("GL context: %x\n", eglContext);
    if (eglContext==0) {
       printf("Error code: %x\n", eglGetError());
       exit(-1) ;
    }

    eglSurface = eglCreateWindowSurface(eglDisplay, eglConfig, displayWindow, NULL);

    printf("GL surface: %x\n", eglSurface);
    if (eglSurface==0) {
       printf("Error code: %x\n", eglGetError());
       exit(-1);
    }

    eglMakeCurrent(eglDisplay, eglSurface, eglSurface, eglContext);

    printf(
        "Vendor: %s, Renderer: %s, Version: %s\n",
        glGetString(GL_VENDOR),
        glGetString(GL_RENDERER),
        glGetString(GL_VERSION)
    ) ;

    printf("Extensions: %s\n", glGetString(GL_EXTENSIONS)) ;

    printf("Spinning triangle for 20s\n") ;

    while (now() - start_time < 20.0) {
        draw_tri();
        eglSwapBuffers(eglDisplay, eglSurface);
    }

    printf("End (tap the screen of the phone to continue).\n") ;

    return 0;
}
```